# Does using "will" connote a desire?

Tags: sentence-meaning

When I say for example:

*"Will I be in trouble___?"* *(if I do it)* **to  imply**  *"Am I going to get in trouble.."*

Could it mean or does it connote also, a little bit, *"I want to be in trouble"*, *"shall we be trouble"* or *"can I be in trouble"* since the word **will** can be used in request sentences?

We can assume this sentence was said by someone who wants to be trouble.

**e.g.**

*Will you marry me?*

*Will/would you do a favor for me?*

Comment: No. There is an important distinction between Will used for the future form, and Will used to make formal requests.

Comment: to avoid ambiguity, use 'would' for a request. It's fine! *Would you mind upvoting this comment?"* :)

Answer (score 3):

Although one of the usages of *"will"* is used to make a formal request, it does not mean all usages of *"will"* in question will become a request.

> Will I be in trouble_____?

It is a simple future tense question asking if you will be in trouble if you do the action.

**e.g.** Will I be in trouble if I take the pen?

You can make it connote a desire of wanting to be in trouble by changing it to **shall** since the definition is *[to express an intention](https://www.google.com.sg/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20shall)* although it may not sound right.

**i.e.** Shall I be in trouble if I take the pen?

> Will you marry me?

Normally, it does sound like a request. However, grammatically, it is not a request at all; it is a future tense question.

**e.g.** Will you marry me *if I quit smoking*?

Is it more clearer with that example?

> Would you do a favor for me?

Almost, but this is wrong. It should be: *Can you do a favor for me?* since it is asking for a possibility.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with "Would you do a favor for me".  It is more polite (and accurate) than "Can you do a favor for me." It is **not** about _possibility_, it is about _willingness_.

Answer (score 0):

> Will ***I*** ***be*** in trouble

creates a special situation.
And it does not mean I want to be in trouble.
It is not request but a question...
Imperative vs. Interrogative sentence